# Prove idempotency of type-level disjunction

Tags: haskell

I've defined type-level disjunction as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, TypeFamilies #-}

type family Or (a :: Bool) (b :: Bool) :: Bool
type instance Or False a = a
type instance Or True a = True
```

Now I'd like to prove (in Haskell) that it is idempotent. That is, I want to build a term `idemp` with type

```
idemp :: a ~ b => proxy (Or a b) -> proxy a
```

which is operationally equivalent to `id`. (Obviously, I can define it e.g. as `unsafeCoerce`, but that's cheating.)

Is it possible?

Comment: My suspicion is that you can't do this in Haskell without some additional constraint on proxy.  A handwavey proof is that you somehow need to construct a value with type `proxy a`, and you don't know how to construct `proxy`s, nor change the values within them.  Are constraints on `proxy` acceptable?

Comment: "Prove idempotency of type-level disjunction" is an awesome question title.

Comment: @JohnL: it's clear how to do it using constraints. But in the context of theorem proving it would correspond to an assumption, not proof.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The thing that you ask for is not possible, but something quite like it might do instead. It's not possible because the proof requires a case analysis on type level Booleans, but you have no data which enables you to make such an event occur. The fix is to include just such information via a singleton.

First up, let me note that your type for `idemp` is a little obfuscated. The constraint `a ~ b` just names the same thing twice. The following typechecks:

```
idemq :: p (Or b b) -> p b
idemq = undefined
idemp :: a ~ b => p (Or a b) -> p a
idemp = idemq
```

(If you have a constraint `a ~ t` where `t` does not contain `a`, it's usually good to substitute `t` for `a`. The exception is in `instance` declarations: an `a` in an instance head will match anything, hence the instance will fire even if that thing has not yet obviously become `t`. But I digress.)

I claim `idemq` is undefinable because we have no useful information about `b`. The only data available inhabit `p`-of-something, and we don't know what `p` is.

We need to reason by cases on `b`. Bear in mind that with general recursive type families, we can define type level Booleans which are neither `True` nor `False`. If I switch on `UndecidableInstances`, I can define

```
type family Loop (b :: Bool) :: Bool
type instance Loop True = Loop False
type instance Loop False = Loop True
```

so `Loop True` cannot be reduced to `True` or `False`, and locally worse, there is no way to show that

```
Or (Loop True) (Loop True) ~ Loop True     -- this ain't so
```

There's no way out of it. We need run time evidence that our `b` is one of the well behaved Booleans that computes somehow to a value. Let us therefore *sing*

```
data Booly :: Bool -> * where
  Truey   :: Booly True
  Falsey  :: Booly False
```

If we know `Booly b`, we can do a case analysis which will tell us what `b` is. Each case will then go through nicely. Here's how I'd play it, using an equality type defined with `PolyKinds` to pack up the facts, rather than abstracting over uses `p b`.

```
data (:=:) a b where
  Refl :: a :=: a
```

Our key fact is now plainly stated and proven:

```
orIdem :: Booly b -> Or b b :=: b
orIdem Truey   = Refl
orIdem Falsey  = Refl
```

And we can deploy this fact by strict case analysis:

```
idemp :: Booly b -> p (Or b b) -> p b
idemp b p = case orIdem b of Refl -> p
```

The case analysis must be strict, to check that the evidence is not some loopy lie, but rather an honest to goodness `Refl` silently packing up just the proof of `Or b b ~ b` that's needed to fix up the types.

If you don't want to sling all these singleton values around explicitly, you can, as kosmikus suggests, hide them in a dictionary and extract them just when you need them.

Richard Eisenberg and Stephanie Weirich have a Template Haskell library which mills these families and classes for you. SHE can build them too and lets you write

```
orIdem pi b :: Bool. Or b b :=: b
orIdem {True}   = Refl
orIdem {False}  = Refl
```

where `pi b :: Bool.` expands to `forall b :: Bool. Booly b ->`.

But it's such a palaver. That's why my gang are working on adding an actual `pi` to Haskell, being a non-parametric quantifier (distinct from `forall` and `->`) which can be instantiated by stuff in the now nontrivial intersection between Haskell's type and term languages. This `pi` could also have an "implicit" variant, where the argument is by default kept hidden. The two respectively correspond to using singleton families and classes, but there's no need to define datatypes three times over to get the additional kit.

It might be worth mentioning that in a total type theory, it is *not* needed to pass the extra copy of the Boolean `b` at run time. The thing is, `b` is used only to make the proof that data may be transported from `p (Or b b)` to `p b`, not necessarily to make the data being transported. We don't compute under binders at run time, so there's no way to cook up a dishonest proof of the equation, hence we can erase the proof component and the copy of `b` that delivers it. As Randy Pollack says, *the best thing about working in a strongly normalizing calculus is not having to normalize things*.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the superfluous equality constraint (which, as you can see in the question history, I removed at one point, but then decided to revert the change) — I wasn't sure that two instances of `Or a a` would unify, due to non-injectivity of type families.

Comment: It doesn't take injectivity to show that `Or a b ~ Or b b ` whenever `a ~ b`, but I don't know what GHC's constraint solver actually does. Sometimes it's distinctly unwilling (for understandable reasons) to infer values of unification variables from constraints on type families. I suspect that you get more traction if you have fewer variables, hence more chances to solve them and more constraints which just need to be checked. But that's voodoo, not science.

Comment: "It doesn't take injectivity to show that" — no; but the solver has to be optimistic. "I'll try to prove that `a ~ b`; and then, if it turns out to be true, I will have proved that `Or a b ~ Or b b`."

Comment: This doesn't happen in a vacuum. If you demand a type involving `Or b b` and you supply two candidates for `b`, it will be necessary to check that they are equal. But we're reduced to second-guessing the solving strategy in order to predict the success or failure of typechecking, which saddens me.

Answer (score 7):

As John L says in his comment, there's currently no way to do this without additional constraints, as far as I know. You cannot exploit the fact that `Bool` is a closed kind on the term level, and there's no way to do case analysis on the type variable of kind `Bool` in `idemp`.

The typical solution is to reflect the `Bool` kind structure on the term level using singleton types:

```
data SBool :: Bool -> * where
  SFalse :: SBool False
  STrue  :: SBool True
```

For any `b :: Bool`, there's just one inhabitant of `SBool b` (modulo `undefined`, of course).

With `SBool`, the theorem is easy to prove (I don't know why you added the extra equality constraint, I'm going to remove it):

```
idemp' :: SBool a -> proxy (Or a a) -> proxy a
idemp' SFalse x = x
idemp' STrue  x = x
```

Instead of passing the argument explicitly, you can pass it implicitly, by defining a class that can create the `SBool` representation:

```
class CBool (b :: Bool) where
  sBool :: SBool b

instance CBool True  where sBool = STrue
instance CBool False where sBool = SFalse
```

Then:

```
idemp :: CBool a => proxy (Or a a) -> proxy a
idemp = idemp' sBool
```

I don't think you can get rid of the `CBool` constraint, but it is trivially true for any `a :: Bool`, so it's not a very strong assumption.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the equality constraint, see my reply to Conor.